# Is it possible to check if a property is nil without calling the getter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, getter, null

I have a `UILabel` property that often will be `nil`, but I have coded it such that when I use it, if it is `nil`, it will be initialized and ready to be used via a getter. However, I have created a bug, because when I check to see if this property is `nil`, it initializes it so that it no longer is `nil`.

**Is it possible to find out if a property is `nil` without calling its getter method?**

```
if (self.myLabel) {
    //run code when this property already is initialized, but don't if it is nil
}

//Getter:
- (UILabel *)myLabel {
    if (!_myLabel) {
        _myLabel = [UILabel alloc] init...
    }
}
```

Comment: You answered your own question.  Look at how your getter does it.

Comment: You can even access the ivar from a different class, if you don't mind cheating a bit.  (You'd get burned, of course, if the ivar name was ever changed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated with discussion below:

Using the call `_myLabel` will allow you to access the variable without calling the getter. However, while the underscore is a standard convention, it is not neccessary, and by simply calling the variable you will also access the internal variable directly.

Comment: FYI - it has nothing to do with *"the _ syntax"*. It's simply a matter of directly accessing the ivar which may or may not be named with an underscore.

Comment: Are you sure? I was under the impression that in objective-C the underscore is what defined accessing an internal variable directly. If that is not the case, how would you access the variable without an underscore?

Comment: I'm 100% sure. The underscore is just a standard naming convention but it is not required. You access the ivar exactly the same whether it's named with an underscore or not.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be providing a separate `BOOL` property that tells the caller if the `_myLabel` variable is `nil` or not:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL isLabelSet;
...
-(BOOL)isLabelSet {
    return _myLabel != nil;
}
```

Assuming that you have source code of the class, you could also enable direct access to the baking variable by declaring it explicitly, and marking it `@public`, but doing so would break encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is to change:

```
if (self.myLabel) {
```

to:

```
if (_myLabel) {
```